# Java connect four victory check

Tags: java

I am a beginner at programming and I have been teaching myself as much as I can. I need help in a simpler way of checking for a victory instead of hard coding every possible combination. 
I have no idea what to do.
here is my current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class connectfour extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel board[][] = new JLabel[8][7];
    //JLabel board[] = new JLabel[64];
    JButton action[] = new JButton[8];
    JButton start;
    JButton clear;
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("red piece.jpeg");
    ImageIcon black = new ImageIcon("blackpiece.jpeg");

    boolean players = true;
    //Integer[] numclick = new Integer[8];
    int x;

    int numclick1 = 7;
    int numclick2 = 7;
    int numclick3 = 7;
    int numclick4 = 7;
    int numclick5 = 7;
    int numclick6 = 7;
    int numclick7 = 7;
    int numclick0 = 7;


    public connectfour()
    {
        Frame.setSize(100,120);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setLayout(null);
        Frame.setVisible(true);

        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        start.setVisible(true);
        start.addActionListener(this);
        Frame.add(start);
    }

    public void game()
    {

        for(int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++)
        {
            action[x] = new JButton();
            action[x].setSize(100,40);
            action[x].setLocation((x*100) + 50, 0);
            action[x].addActionListener(this);
            action[x].setVisible(true);
            Frame.add(action[x]);
        }
        /**
        board[1][1] = new JLabel();
        board[1][1].setBounds(50,40,100,100);
        board[1][1].setVisible(true);
        board[1][1].setOpaque(true);
        board[1][1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        Frame.add(board[1][1]);
        **/
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
            board[i][j] = new JLabel();
            board[i][j].setSize(100,100);
            board[i][j].setLocation((i*100)+50,(j*100)+40);
            board[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            board[i][j].setVisible(true);
            board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            Frame.add(board[i][j]);

            }
        }   

        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        clear.setBounds(850,100,100,50);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        clear.setVisible(true);
        Frame.add(clear);


    }
    public void boardsize()
   {
        Frame.setSize(950,800);
   }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new connectfour();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource() == start)
        {
            boardsize();
            start.setVisible(false);
            game();

        }
        for(x = 0;x < 8 ;x ++)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == action[x])
            {
                //numclick[x]++;
                if(x == 0)
                {
                    numclick0--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick0].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick0].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(x == 1)
                {
                    numclick1--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick1].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick1].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 2)
                {
                    numclick2--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick2].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick2].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 3)
                {
                    numclick3--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick3].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick3].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 4)
                {
                    numclick4--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick4].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick4].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 5)
                {
                    numclick5--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick5].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick5].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 6)
                {
                    numclick6--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick6].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick6].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x == 7)
                {
                    numclick7--;
                    if(players == true)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick7].setIcon(red);
                        players = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(players == false)
                    {
                        board[x][numclick7].setIcon(black);
                        players = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println();


            }
        }   
        if(e.getSource() == clear)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
                {
                    board[x][y].setIcon(null);

                    numclick1 = 7;
                    numclick2 = 7;
                    numclick3 = 7;
                    numclick4 = 7;
                    numclick5 = 7;
                    numclick6 = 7;
                    numclick7 = 7;
                    numclick0 = 7;

                    players = true;

                    for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++)
                    {
                        action[j].setEnabled(true);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if(numclick0 == 0)
        {
            action[0].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick1 == 0)
        {
            action[1].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick2 == 0)
        {
            action[2].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick3 == 0)
        {
            action[3].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick4 == 0)
        {
            action[4].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick5 == 0)
        {
            action[5].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick6 == 0)
        {
            action[6].setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(numclick7 == 0)
        {
            action[7].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void winner()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your victory criteria?

Comment: You might want to go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to first clean it up (assuming the current code works). This is too verbose. After it is cleaned up, you can look into the victory check.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a recursive method that checks the horizontal, vertical, and both diagonals.

As i was reading your code I realized you don't keep track(may have missed it) of where players are.. I recommend and array for this called `grid[][]` Mapping an array to your JLabels will go a long way.

Ill give an example of negative vertical check..

```
 public Boolean checkVertical(Boolean player, int x, int y){
      if(solveHelper(player, x, y, -1, 0) => 4) return true;
      return false;
 }

public int solveHelper(Boolean player, int x, int y, int addX, int addY){
     if(x == 0 || x == size || y == 0 || y == size || grid[x][y].player != player) 
          return 0;
     return solverHelper(player, x+addX, y+addY, addX, addY) + 1);
}
```

Now how can you create and use these methods for yourself?

you need to create a new methods for each of the horizontal, vertical, and both diagonals to check for all of them you call `solveHelper` with different properties in `addX` and `addY` that correspond with the direction you want to go. For instance, if you want to check the horizontal you need do make `addY == 1` and `addY == -1` with both values for `addX == 0` by doing a `solveHelper + solverHelper` with these two values  changed.

Other notes...

Some things you need to need to keep in mind is that how connect four actually runs. When you click on a row a piece falls down to the smallest unoccupied element in that particular column. Just something you should keep in mind when writing your game logic.

Cheers.